# Desktop shortcuts for programs installed in Sandboxie

Tags: windows-7, shortcuts, desktop, sandboxie

When I install a program in Sandboxie (by running the installer sandboxed) it creates all the program data buried inside the sandbox's directory structure. When the installer tries to create a desktop shortcut for what I installed, that also goes into the sandbox's desktop directory, so does not show up on my actual desktop.

Every time I install something in the sandbox I have to tediously dig through the directory structure, and manually create a shortcut. I know that Sandbox has a "Sandbox Start Menu" where you can launch the installed programs, but I don't want to use the menu - I want a desktop shortcut.

Is it possible to have desktop shortcuts be excluded from the Sandboxing, or in some other way set it up so that when I install a program in my sandbox, the shortcut automatically gets copied to my real desktop?

Comment: What you describe would defeat the purpose of sandboxie

Comment: @Ramhound How would making sandboxed programs easy to run defeat the purpose of Sandboxie?

Comment: Because of how Sandboxie works.  It even warns you that, opening files, within its folder, could be dangerous.

Comment: @Ramhound How would that be dangerous if they open sandboxed?

Answer (score 8):

In the Sandboxie Control window, under the Configure tab there should be an option called Windows Shell Integration, clicking on it will open a new window. In this new window you can find a button labeled Add Shortcut Icons, you'll then be prompted to chose a sandbox and a program from the chosen sandbox's start menu, which will then create a shortcut for running that program under Sandboxie.

Answer (score 0):

Create a shortcut to `"C:\Program Files\Sandboxie\Start.exe" /box:NAME_OF_SANDBOX "C:\directory\program.exe"`  You can probably also add arguments after the exe.